# Running Multiple Line Commands with Python

Tags: python

Python has an option that allows us to pass python statements as an argument to the program.

An example usage is

```
$ python -c "print(\"I'm running Python.\")"
I'm running Python.
```

In Python's man page we read

```
when called with -c command, it executes the
       Python statement(s) given as command.  Here command may contain  multi‐
       ple  statements  separated by newlines.
```

I'm trying to pass in multiple lines, but can't:

```
$ python -c "print(0)\nprint(1)"
  File "<string>", line 1
    print(0)\nprint(1)
                     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

I also tried Here-documents without success. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use here-doc's supported by your shell, instead of relying on the own options from `python`. This way you need to do a multi-level nesting of your quotes and type your code free-form as you can do on a script.

The `-` after the `python` executable means that the commands to run are coming from the standard input which you are feeding from the here-doc. Most utilities implement this, i.e. a `-` after a command means that an input is coming over from standard input which needs to be parsed.

```
python - <<'EOF'
print("I'm running Python.")
print("Are you now?")
EOF
```

Also literal escaped `\n` are not recognized by the shell without commands that make use of them like `printf` or `echo -e`. The string within `".."` is processed by the underlying shell before passing it over to the executable. Since there is no special processing available for the literal `\n`, the shell does not expand it over to multiple lines.

You should still generate the line break implicitly while using `-c` by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on the terminal and continue typing the next set of commands

```
python -c "print(0)
> print(1)"
```

One other way to still use `python -c` and do this would be to defined the string in such a way that the embedded newlines are parsed within `".."`. One way to do in `bash`/`zsh` would be to use [ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) and do

```
python -c $'print(0)\nprint(1)'
```

i.e. within the `$'..'` the `\n` and few other escape sequences are expanded by the shell before passing it over the executable. Now your `python` interpreter sees two separate lines passed to it.

Also there is very well written cross-site dupe on [StackOverflow - Executing multi-line statements in the one-line command-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2043453/5291015) explaining this.